# How update postgresql table from azure databricks with spark/jdbc?

Tags: postgresql, azure, jdbc, databricks

I was able to connect to the JDBC driver that I installed on the Azure Databricks cluster with the following statement:

```
remote_table = (spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("driver", driver)
  .option("url", url)
  .option("dbtable", table)
  .option("user", user)
  .option("password", password)
  .load()
  )
```

I was able to successfully load this dataframe and update certain rows with this code:

```
remote_table = remote_table.withColumn("status", when(remote_table.transactionKey == transaction_key, "sucess").otherwise(remote_table.status))
```

Now I try to update (save with the overwrite mode) the table in the database but I either get an empty table or an unchanged table when I reload it. To save the table I have tried both of these codes:

```
remote_table.write \
  .format("jdbc") \
  .option("url", url) \
  .option("dbtable", table) \
  .option("user", user) \
  .option("password", password) \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .save()
```

OR

```
remote_table.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("remote")
```

Any hint on why this is not working? I don't get an error message, just not the result that I expect. Thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT: I used a different approach in the end to overcome this problem, I used the psycopg2 with the following code and it's working:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql

def update_table(transaction_key):
""" update status of request based on the transaction key """
query = sql.SQL("update {table} set {column}='success' where {key} = %s").format(
table=sql.Identifier('table_name'),
column=sql.Identifier('status'),
key=sql.Identifier('transactionKey'))

conn = None
updated_rows = 0
try:
    # read database configuration (hard coded for now)
    params = {"host": "...", "port": "5432", "dbname": "...", "user": "...", "password": "..."}
    # connect to the PostgreSQL database
    conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
    # create a new cursor
    cur = conn.cursor()
    # execute the UPDATE  statement
    cur.execute(query, (transaction_key,))
    # get the number of updated rows
    updated_rows = cur.rowcount
    # Commit the changes to the database
    conn.commit()
    # Close communication with the PostgreSQL database
    cur.close()
except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    print(error)
finally:
    if conn is not None:
        conn.close()

return updated_rows
```

I got inspired from another code snippet I found but I cannot find the website anymore!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the same scenario in my environment and faced similar issue while writing data in Postgres sql  from databricks dataframe.

It is only creating table but not inserting the rows in it. With this [document](https://docs.databricks.com/external-data/jdbc.html#language-sql) you can insert data using `jdbc` through `SQL`,

The work around you can try is you can write the data with Databricks SQL query.

- First create a temp view for data frame  with below syntax

```sql
remote_table1.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_view_name")
```

[image]

- Then Write that temp view data into Postgres SQL table using below code:

```sql
%sql
CREATE  TABLE  new_employees_table
  USING  JDBC
OPTIONS  (
  url  "<jdbc_url>",
  dbtable  "<table_name>",
  user  '<username>',
  password  '<password>'
)  AS
SELECT  *  FROM  employees_table_vw
```

[image]

***Output inserting data***

[image]

for Spark or Scala it is not inserting data. check if your dataframe has values or not if still issue persist you can raise a  [support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to Microsoft for deeper investigation

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in the end I used another library and it worked out (see edit above)